# Best method for daily incremental copy of Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, heroku

I'm trying to figure out the best plan of attack for making a nightly copy of our Heroku PostgreSQL production database to our local development environment.

The database is rather large and grows at roughly 250,000 rows per day. Ideally the solution would be an incremental method and only restore the previous days changes.

Our development environment is also Postgres running on OSX.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: For normal non-hosted PostgreSQL you'd use WAL archiving/streaming replication.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Would this apply to my situation being that my source database is hosted and my target database is non-hosted?

Looks like I have some reading to do today. :)

Comment: As far as I can tell Heroku doesn't let you get WAL out of their system, and you'd need an identical binary-compatible Pg and a matching base backup. You might have to use dumps, or a trigger based replication system like Bucardo.